# Show that if $n$ is a positive integer greater than $1$, then the Mersenne number $M_n$ cannot be the power of a positive integer.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers, mersenne-numbers

## Question

Show that if $n$ is a positive integer greater than $1$, then the [Mersenne number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html) $M_n$ cannot be the power of a positive integer.

## My Progress

**As Image**
[image]

**As Text**

Let $M_n = 2^n - 1$ be a Mersenne number.  Suppose that $M_n = q^k$ for some $q \in \mathbb{N}$.

$M_n$ is odd $\implies q$ is odd.

Suppose that $k = 2k_1$.  This implies that $M_n = 2^n - 1 = (q^{k_1})^2$.

But the square of an odd integer is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.  However, $2^n - 1$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ for $n > 1$.

This is a contradiction.  Therefore, $k$ has to be odd, and we have the equation
$$2^n = a^k + 1 = (a + 1)(1 - a + a^2 - a^3 + \ldots + (-1)^{k-1} a^{k-1}) = (a + 1)(1 - a + a^2 - a^3 + \ldots + a^{k-1}).$$
This implies that we have
$$a = 2^m - 1$$
for some $m$.  This means that we have
$$a^k = (2^m - 1)^k \implies 2^n - 1 = (2^m - 1)^k.$$

How should I proceed?

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset the math. equations

Comment: sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Catalan's conjecture (proved as Mihailescu's Theorem) says that the only example of two consecutive integers that are perfect powers ($>1$) is $8,9$. Therefore, $2^n$ cannot be one greater than any perfect power $q^k$.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4174692/930909).

Comment: Got it. Thanks all.

Comment: $(2^m-1)^2=(2^{m-1}-1)(2^{m+1}-1)+2^{m-1}=2^{2m}-2^{m+1}+1$